# Differences in Bansuri Fingering Chart

Tags: fingering, woodwinds, indian-classical, bansuri

I have been practicing little over a month roughly 30 minutes a day. Bansuri is A scale, almost 23.5"

---

So far I am practicing `SA RE GA MA PA DHA NI SA`, and using higher octave when doing `PA DHA NI SA`.

Now I am seeing there is a more complex Bansuri Fingering Chart. Is this for more advanced users? I find it very odd there are three blowing pressures, rather than two blowing pressures

Website is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bansuri

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct. The pressure for reaching the pa, dha, ni and sa of higher octave is much higher and the finger positions will be slightly different. Of course these are for advanced practice. Nevertheless you can also try

Comment: Also The chart you have pasted gives the fingerings for the sharp(tivra) and flat (komal) notes also. All r,g,d,n are komal (flat) notes and R,G,M,D,N are Shuddha (natural). and 'm' is Tivra (Sharp) notes. For komal notes, you have to close the holes half (not exactly half; it depends on the raga). That's why they have showed some holes grey